# Higher bandwidth in texture memory compared to global memory

Tags: cuda, profiling, textures, nvidia, hpc

Texture memory is a part of global memory. It is cached and read-only. But for a 2D stencil heat problem, a lot of literature suggests using texture memory. The time taken (gpu__time_duration.sum) decreases on using texture memory, but the memory throughput increases too (dram__bytes.sum.per_second). Why will the memory throughput increase? It is accessing data from the slower global memory at the end, so why will the throughput increase? I can not find any literature pointing to it.

Comment: This is probably because of how the data is cached. When accessing normal global memory, the cache will consist of the elements that are spatially close in 1D, meaning the elements right before and right after the accessed element. Texture memory optimizes caching based on 2D locality. Thinking of an image, accessing the pixel right below you is slow for normal global memory (since it is not close to your pixel in 1D), but it is fast for texture memory. See the [CUDA Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: From the CUDA C-Programming Guid: "The texture cache is optimized for 2D spatial locality, so threads of the same warp that read texture or surface addresses that are close together in 2D will achieve best performance."

Comment: Memory throughput = data read / execution time. If execution time decreases for a constant amount of data it stands to reason that memory  throughput must increase

Comment: @M.Steiner, yes I understand that point, but by performance I assume they meant less time taken to execute the kernel and not the higher throughput. I am unable to understand the increase in throughput

Comment: Well, how does `dram__bytes_read.sum` change? (not `sum.per_second`) If it's roughly the same or even went down, that just means the cache did its job and reduced the compute time. If the threads spend less time stalled waiting for memory requests, the remaining requests will be packed in a closer window of time, increasing the throughput.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment, texture memory is using a different cache than a buffer in global memory : "The texture cache is optimized for 2D spatial locality, so threads of the same warp that read texture or surface addresses that are close together in 2D will achieve best performance."

When profiling with NSight, you could access the [Memory Statistics](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/developertools/desktop/analysis/report/cudaexperiments/kernellevel/memorystatisticscaches.htm) to understand how your code is "using" the caches.

And the fact that texture is read only allows a different caching strategy that allows higher bandwidth.

So the speedup will depend on how you access your memory.